# Trying to slow down

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I made this command where u can fake hack someone but every time it edits the message too fast I'm just trying to see how can I slow it down where it just plows every single edited message where I cant see

````js
message.channel.send(`Hacking ${votedu.username} now...`).then(msg => {
            try {

                 msg.edit('[▖] Finding discord login... (2fa bypassed)')
                 msg.edit(`[▘] Found:\n**Email:** \`${votedu.username}eatsButt@hotmail.com\`n**Password:** \`1234567890\``);
                 msg.edit('[▝] Fetching dms with closest friends (if there are any friends at all)');
                 msg.edit('[▗] **Last DM:** "I hope no one sees my nudes folder"');
                 msg.edit('[▖] Finding most common word...');
                 msg.edit('[▘] `const mostCommonWord: string = \'small\';`');
                 msg.edit('[▝] Injecting trojan virus into discriminator #6218');
                 msg.edit('[▗] Virus injected, emotes stolen :pepecreepylurk:');
                 msg.edit('[▖] Setting up Epic Store account..');
                 msg.edit('[▘] Hacking Epic Store account.... :chugMyJug:');
                 msg.edit('[▝] Finding IP address');
                 msg.edit('[▗] **IP address:** 127.0.0.1:8100');
                 msg.edit('[▖] Selling data to the Government...');
                 msg.edit('[▘] Reporting account to Discord for breaking TOS...');
                 msg.edit('Finished hacking Helia');*/

            }
    ```
````

Comment: You can try `setTimeout()` to schedule the edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you didn't wait between the edits.

To wait between each edit, you can use this simple line of code between each message edit.

`await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));`

You can change `1000` to any number of milliseconds you want.

Comment: i seem to not understand this `new Promise`